# MenuItem clickable area

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have a `ContextMenu`, in which I'm binding a submenu to a collection of custom objects. At click I'm sending a command with the bound object as parameter:

```
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Launch" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}">
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.LaunchProfileCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                                <local:ProfileView IconSize="24" NameFontSize="10"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                   </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
```

The issue is that not the whole area of the `MenuItem` (one per each item in 'Profiles' collection) will trigger the bound command. Only red area will trigger the command:

[image]

I have tried to change the `Padding` and `Margin` properties of the `MenuItem` style with no success.

How can I achieve to be able to click anywhere in the `MenuItem` and be able to trigger the bound command?

Note: the red area corresponds to my custom view: `ProfileView`. Margins of this view are set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting a menu item inside another menu item. You don't need to do that. Set properties on the Launch submenu child menu items with `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Launch" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter 
                    Property="Command" 
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.LaunchProfileCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                    />
                <Setter 
                    Property="CommandParameter"
                    Value="{Binding}"
                    />
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <local:ProfileView IconSize="24" NameFontSize="10"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Highlighting has stopped working on MenuItems, can it be caused by using templated controls (Mahapps)?

Comment: @Sturm Right, the control template handles that, and you replaced the control template. I've updated my version to use HeaderTemplate instead. If you really do want to eliminate the existing control template entirely, you'll have to give your new ControlTemplate some triggers to handle highlighting etc.

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding a style trigger:                              `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9F6DFF" /></Trigger>` and then placing my control inside a `Grid` with `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`